# What should I do to develop a well structed C++ program?

Tags: c++, user-interface, module

Right now, I want to develop a C++ program.
 And the UI design is the difficult issue.
 my question is:
1. is there any good practice for developing a well structed c++ program ?
2. is there any good practice for developing UI in c++?
3. I usually heard of Activex in C++, can it use to encapsulate a UI, and is good for maintain after software is finished.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I honestly can't understand your question. Are you asking how can you write a Graphical User Interface application with C++, instead of using just the console? For windows? Linux Gnome, KDE?

Comment: I just want to encapsulate a UI into a module.
just like in asp.net, you can insert a .ascx into a aspx page.

Comment: You need to be more specific. A "UI module" could mean anything - a web page, a javascript library UI component, a Windows control, an ATL UI component, etc.

Comment: yeah, I just don't know what control i can write in c++. Otherwise, why do i come here to ask questions ?

Comment: Please reformulate your entire question and ask us what you want to do. Not how you want to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try to give some answers to your questions:

**1) Good Program Structure**

This really depends on what matters most - cost of development, ease of deployment/update, maintainability, target machine requirements. It is hard to give you a good answer because the topic is so large. I suggest this as a good place to start reading:

[Software Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design)

**(2) Good Practice for developing UI**

This really does depend on what technology you are going to use. If you're running on Windows, you have a handful of options:

a) Win32 API programming

This is the hardest and involves writing code to call functions like 'CreateWindow' to create your UI a piece at a time.

b) ATL - Active Template Library

This is a bit easier than (1) but uses really hardcore C++ - you need to know about Templates, Multiple Inheritance, some Patterns and you'll end up learning Win32 anyway.

c) Microsoft Foundation Classes (MFC)

If you have Visual C++ or Visual Studio, you can create an MFC project which has dialog editors and a UI framework to more easily create rich user interfaces. Microsoft Outlook is written in MFC.

d) Use C#.net

If you have Visual Studio, then I would recommend that you make your UI in Visual C# using the Forms Designer tool as it is quite easy to create a flexible and responsive UI. You can still do all your business logic in C++ and link to it from the C#. It is also the newest of all these options.

**3) ActiveX**

For all options (a), (b), (c), (d) you can make an ActiveX control to make your program re-usable. You can also make an ActiveX control in Visual Basic.

Hope this helps!

James

Answer (score 2):

You might also consider using Qt - crossplatform UI framework for C++.